# Can not install NativeBase

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image]*****emphasized** I tried to install NativeBase and it came out like this. Can anyone help me !***

Comment: try it with `yarn add native-base --save`

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: run `rm package-lock.json && npm i && npm i --save native-base`